python sympy does not simplify the complex roots of unity
Consider the following sympy expression
(1 - (-1)**(Rational(1,3)) + exp(2*I*pi/3))/(3*(1 + exp(I*pi/3)))

the .simplify() and .rewrite(exp) does not lead to the identity 0.
Basically, the simplification function does not response to the complex roots of unity very well, and is a bit unstable. Is there a way to tell sympy that the above expression is 0? or is there a way to simplify it to 0?

Why do you use Rational(1,3) instead of just 1/3?  Those are different values.

@TimRoberts it's a package thing. 1/3 in python are recognized as the integer division and natively converted into the float32 object, but Rational(1,3) became symbolic object in sympy package and are in the filed of rationals. It's the same as Integer(1)/Integer(3) which sympy recognized it as the symbolic math. Rational(1,3) was a short abbreviation.

SymPy's nsimplify function can simplify numeric expressions like this semi-heuristically using number identification (e.g. PSLQ):
In [8]: e = (1 - (-1)**(Rational(1,3)) + exp(2*I*pi/3))/(3*(1 + exp(I*pi/3)))

In [9]: e
Out[9]: 
              2⋅ⅈ⋅π
              ─────
    3 ____      3  
1 - ╲╱ -1  + ℯ     
───────────────────
           ⅈ⋅π     
           ───     
            3      
    3 + 3⋅ℯ        

In [10]: nsimplify(e)
Out[10]: 0

Converting the expression into a Poly with extension=True does this non-heuristically for any algebraic number by computing minimal polynomials and constructing extension fields in which algebraic numbers have canonical representations:
In [13]: e.as_poly(z, extension=True)
Out[13]: Poly(0, z, domain='QQ<(-1)**(1/3)>')

In [14]: e.as_poly(z, extension=True).as_expr()
Out[14]: 0

In [15]: minpoly(e)
Out[15]: x

Here z is a symbol and is needed just so that a Poly can be constructed. The lower-level interface for this sort of thing is like:
In [2]: K, [e_K] = construct_domain([e], extension=True)

In [3]: K
Out[3]: QQ<(-1)**(1/3)>

In [4]: e_K
Out[4]: ANP([], [27, -27, 27], QQ)

In [5]: K.to_sympy(e_K)
Out[5]: 0

